# MVC4 Partial View @Html Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, partial

I am working on small project in MVC4, and am having an extremely weird issue with partial views. It is a fresh project.

If I add a new partial view, inside the partial view, I am unable to access any of the razor @Html.thing helpers. No @Html.BeginForm or @Html.TextBox or anything. This behavior is only occuring in my partial views, I can access and use all of those without issue in a full view.

Inside of the partial view, if I type @using Html.BeginForm() { , I get the following error message "The type or namespace 'Html' could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I'm at a total loss on this one, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wow...Never mind this question. I am a total idiot. Forgot to put the opening parentheses. Spent entirely too long on that one